# BlackBerry RecordStore - How to make private or shared?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, midp

OK, per the [BB manual](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_data_for_midlets_1554323_11.jsp):

*"Applications that use the record store can either make data private or allow sharing. The record store is frequently used to share data between applications. "*

Yet, I'm not seeing anything in the examples on how to make a record store private "or allow sharing" within the examples.

Can someone please help clarify? I've very, very new to this stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my own answer:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#openRecordStore%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20int,%20boolean%29

```
public static RecordStore openRecordStore(String recordStoreName,
                                      boolean createIfNecessary,
                                      int authmode,
                                      boolean writable)
                               throws RecordStoreException,
                                      RecordStoreFullException,
                                      RecordStoreNotFoundException
```

"authmode" determines during create determines whether its shared, or private.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't recommend using RecordStore. It's record based, which means hard to use. Try PersistentObject, it's object based, very handy. And it's easy to share data between application, you only need to implement a read/write signature.
For details, please refer to : http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentObject.html#getContents%28net.rim.device.api.system.CodeSigningKey,%20net.rim.device.api.system.CodeSigningKey%29
CodeSigningKey is to controll the access of the stored content.